# FuelPHP $_many_many with where clause

Tags: fuelphp

I have a many to many relationship in FuelPHP as seen below:

```
    protected static $_many_many = array(
    'members' => array(
        'key_from' => 'team_id',
        'key_through_from' => 'team_id', 
        'table_through' => 'user_has_team', 
        'key_through_to' => 'user_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_User',
        'key_to' => 'id',
    )
);
```

But I wanted to know if you can have a where clause in the relationship. For example:

```
    protected static $_many_many = array(
    'members' => array(
        'key_from' => 'team_id',
        'key_through_from' => 'team_id', 
        'table_through' => 'user_has_team', 
        'key_through_to' => 'user_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_User',
        'key_to' => 'id',
        'where' => array('account_status' => 'active')
    )
);
```

So it only returns Model_User objects which have their account_status set to 'active'. I know this is pushing it a bit but Fuel is awesome in lots of other was so I though there might be a way to do this.

Obviously you could do this with a query but I wanted to know if there is a way to do it using $_many_many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late to the party, but for people hitting this one on a search:

You can define conditions on a relationship definition. At the moment 'where' and 'order_by' clauses are supported.

This conditions are permanent, you can't switch them on or off. So if you need both full and filtered access to a related model, you will have to define two relations.

See http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/intro.html#usage_rel_conditions for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function action_your_function_where_you_call_the_user_model()
{

    $user = Model_User::find()->where('account_status', 'active')->get();   

}
```